# Selenium error `AssertionError: Lists differ` in tearDown

Tags: python, selenium-rc

I am a beginner to Python and my first task is to implement automated test scripts for my app build using PHP and Python. For this I started using Selenium IDE and then import the code in Python and paste it into my editor.

But when I am trying to run that script from my editor it's throwing an error :

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test (__main__.dash)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace\test\dash.py", line 70, in tearDown
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != ['False is not True', 'False i...

Second list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
False is not True

- []
+ ['False is not True', 'False is not True']

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 31.641s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

But I have no idea from where this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

In your dash.py, you have the following line

```
self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

which means, that you check that our verificationErrors is empty.

In your run, this list is not empty, it contains two entries :

- False is not True
- True is not False

Basically, this means that your test, whatever it is, is not passing, now without more information, it will be hard to help you more.